# Why recursion is needed in Merge sort algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

```py
def mergeSort(arr): 
    if len(arr) > 1: 
        mid = len(arr) // 2 # Finding the mid of the array 
        L = arr[:mid]       # Dividing the array elements  
        R = arr[mid:]       # into 2 halves 
  
        mergeSort(L)        # Sorting the first half 
        mergeSort(R)        # Sorting the second half 
  
        i = j = k = 0
          
        # Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] 
        while i < len(L) and j < len(R): 
            if L[i] < R[j]: 
                arr[k] = L[i] 
                i += 1
            else: 
                arr[k] = R[j] 
                j += 1
            k += 1
          
        # Checking if any element was left 
        while i < len(L): 
            arr[k] = L[i] 
            i += 1
            k += 1
          
        while j < len(R): 
            arr[k] = R[j] 
            j += 1
            k += 1

def printList(arr): 
    for i in range(len(arr)):         
        print(arr[i], end = " ") 
    print() 
 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
     arr = [12, 11, 13, 5, 6, 7]  
     print("Given array is", end = "\n")  
     printList(arr) 
     mergeSort(arr) 
     print("Sorted array is: ", end = "\n") 
     printList(arr)
```

What is the point of using `mergeSort(L)` and `mergeSort(R)` in the above code as even you remove this recursion, we can get the sorted list. Then why is this necessary? The above code is directly taken from geeks for geeks and also I have seen such recursions in merge sort in many other places as well. What's the point of using it.

And another question is: how can `mergeSort(L)` or even `mergeSort(R)` returns anything without any `return` statement as it simply fails and returns nothing when length of `arr` is < 1.

Comment: Regarding "how can mergesort(L) or even mergesort(R) returns anything without any return statement". The `mergesort` function sorts the list *in-place*. I.e. it modifies the original list you pass. And Please learn more about [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) and [sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) in general.

Comment: Removing the recursive calls may in *some particular* case produce a sorted list, but certainly not in all cases. Try with an array with 100 random numbers.

Comment: "even u remove this recursion, we can get the sorted list": NO !

Comment: There is an iterative version of merge sort, called [bottom up merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation). Most libraries use a variation and hybrid of insertion sort and bottom up merge sort.

Answer (score 0):

The mergeSort function without the recursion does not sort the array, it just merge (hence the name) the two half that are supposed to be already sorted. This is why you need to call the function on each half of the array before merging the two.

Also the mergeSort does not return anything, it just sort the array in place, and doesn't do anything for an array of length less than one because then there's no element to sort.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the recursive calls, you will just merge the two halves `L = [12, 11, 13]` and `R = [5, 6, 7]`.

The contents or `arr` will become as `[5, 6, 7, 12, 11, 13]`, which is **not** sorted.

You might have tested with an array where both halves are already sorted, but in the general case, the recursion is needed.

`mergeSort` does not return anything, it updates `arr` in place.